# Time.timescale affects two scripts?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two scripts in my scene. First one is a slow motion script. Second one is for pause menu. In my pause menu script, I have Time.timescale = 0 or 1 depending whether it's paused or not.

In my slow motion script I also use Time.timescale in order to create "slow motion" effect. For some reason, if pause menu script is enabled, I am unable to use slow motion. If it's disabled, it works just fine. So I came with conclusion that the issue is with Time.timescale (I even tested it).

Here's my pause menu script:

```
public bool isPaused;
    public GameObject canvasPause;

    MouseLook fpCamMouseLook;
    MouseOrbitImproved tpCamOrbitLook;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        fpCamMouseLook = GameObject.Find ("Main Camera").GetComponent<MouseLook> ();
        tpCamOrbitLook = GameObject.Find ("ThirdPersonCamera").GetComponent<MouseOrbitImproved> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Escape)) {

            // switch for pause boolean
            isPaused = !isPaused;
        }

        if (isPaused == true) {

            AudioListener.volume = 0f;

            canvasPause.SetActive (true);
            Time.timeScale = 0;
            fpCamMouseLook.enabled = false;
            tpCamOrbitLook.enabled = false;


        } else {

            AudioListener.volume = 1f;

            canvasPause.SetActive (false);
            Time.timeScale = 1;
            fpCamMouseLook.enabled = true;
            tpCamOrbitLook.enabled = true;

        }

    }

    // back to menu button
    public void goBackToMenu(){

        Application.LoadLevel ("Menu");

    }

    public void quitToDesktop(){

        Application.Quit ();
    }

    public void unPause(){

        canvasPause.SetActive (false);
    }
```

And here's my slow motion script:

```
float currentAmount = 0f;
    float maxAmount = 5f;

    public bool isSlowMo;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab)){

            isSlowMo = !isSlowMo;

            }

        if (isSlowMo == true) {

            if (Time.timeScale == 1.0f)
                Time.timeScale = 0.3f;

        } else {

            Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
            Time.fixedDeltaTime = 0.02f * Time.timeScale;

        }


        if(Time.timeScale == 0.03f){

        currentAmount += Time.deltaTime;

            }

        if(currentAmount > maxAmount){

        currentAmount = 0f;
        Time.timeScale = 1.0f;

        }

    }
```

Please help?

Comment: Time.timeScale is global. Both scripts are changing the field each frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easier solution for myself. I just decided to disable player's inputs on pause instead of pausing time. It worked fine for me. Thanks!